# PushNotification redirect to respected viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I am using push notification in my application. My question is, if user receives a push notification out of the app, user should be able to click that notification banner and be 
brought to the activities page where notification is displayed.

Anybody can help me how to solve this issue. I am new in push notification.

Comment: you need to include information in the push notification user info payload. that the app can then parse and examine, use this to determine what to do when the app opens.

Answer (score 1):

//Use this code in your AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
 {
          //code for navigate to viewcontroller
          ActivityViewController *objActivity = [[ActivityViewController alloc]    initWithNibName:@"ActivityViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationcontroller pushViewController: objActivity animated:YES];

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{




 NSString *aPayload=[userInfo objectForKey:@"payload"];

NSDictionary *JSON =
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [aPayload  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error: NULL];

if ([[JSON objectForKey:@"activity"]isEqualToString:@"encore"]) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Piggyback"
                                                    message: [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]
                                                   delegate: nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"DONE"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
           self.likeBedge=self.likeBedge+1;
   [alert show];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"likeComment" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}


else if ([[JSON objectForKey:@"activity"]isEqualToString:@"like"]||[[JSON objectForKey:@"activity"]isEqualToString:@"comment"]){
    self.likeBedge=self.likeBedge+1;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"likeComment" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}



else if ([[JSON objectForKey:@"activity"]isEqualToString:@"started playing"]){
    self.postBedge=self.postBedge+1;
    NSLog(@"%d",self.postBedge);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"started playing" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}



else if ([[JSON objectForKey:@"activity"]isEqualToString:@"stopped playing"]){
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"stopped playing" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}



else if ([[JSON objectForKey:@"activity"]isEqualToString:@"@user play"]||[[JSON objectForKey:@"activity"]isEqualToString:@"@user comment"]){
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"likeComment" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}


return;
```

}

i have already done this above code but when app is in background and if notification is come user tap on banner it should redirect to activity page

Answer (score 0):

So when the application goes to background and you receive a notification the method you are going to call in appdelegate.m file is

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    // Here present the class you want 
}
```